# Only allow users on my network domain to open an Excel workbook

Tags: excel, passwords, vba

Rather than distribute a password to employees, I would like to protect an excel workbook so that only users on the company domain can open the workbook.  Is there a feasible way to do this?

The workbook should be encrypted, but transparently decrypted for users who are logged into the company domain.  That way, a file that strays from the internal network will not be opened.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a way to encrypt a file and decrypt it without user being prompted to type a password.
Anyway, you can use an AcitveDirectory to set authorizations for user to be able to change a protected range.

Regards,
Max

Comment: Agreed. I think your best bet is to put it on a network share and permission it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Setting permissions on the network share won't prevent an employee from copy/pasting the file elsewhere, effectively removing the security if the file didn't have a password.

Another option would be to create an add-in to handle the opening of the workbooks.

The user should save the workbooks without a password, after which a central process re-opens the workbook and saves it again with a certain password, where the password is also stored somewhere else accessible to the add-in for later use (up to you how to devise this scheme).

Your users could then use a form triggered by a button in the add-in's ribbon to specify which protected file to open.  The add-in then looks up the correct password for it, after which it in turn opens the file supplying the password in the process.  The user is thus oblivious of a password being used.

How manageable and fool-proof this all is I leave up to figure out yourself :)

Comment: ... and only now I see the question is from 2010...  Ah well, better late than never :)